# Until which version of iText should com.lowagie packages be imported?

Tags: java, itext

I am using v5.4.5 and `com.lowagie` is not recognized. Instead we have to specify `com.itextpdf`.

eg: `import com.itextpdf.text.Document;`

I wanted to know until which version did we have to write `import com.lowagie.text.Document;`?

Answer (score 2):

For everything before iText 5, you need to import the packages named after me, but please read http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq if you do. Starting with iText 5, I've changed the package names to `com.itextpdf` which was a good decision, because people started talking about me as if i was a product.

Comment: Nevertheless my thanks for the product. Earlier having done work on the PDF format myself, I admire the effort involved.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the latest MPL licensed (free) version is 4.2.1. After that the licensing seems to be not so liberal anymore.

The build tool maven handles dependencies/version of libraries and might be of interest for such queries.